# AWS WAFv2 Terraform import ID issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, wafv2

I'm trying to import a aws_wafv2 web acl that I've created via the console. I setup the terraform up but for some reason it won't let me import, it says my ID is not available. Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Here is my main.tf

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "waf_acl_buddyman" {
  name        = "waf_acl_buddyman"
  description = "WAF ACL for buddyman"
  id = data.terraform_remote_state.aws_wafv2_web_acl.outputs.aws_wafv2_web_acl_af_acl_buddyman_id
  scope       = "REGIONAL"
  default_action {
    allow {}
  }
  visibility_config {
    cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    metric_name                = "waf_acl_buddyman"
    sampled_requests_enabled   = true
  }
  rule {
    name     = "waf_buddyman_acl"
    priority = 0
    override_action {
      count {}
    }
    statement {
      managed_rule_group_statement {
        name        = "AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet"
        vendor_name = "AWS"
        excluded_rule {
          name = "SizeRestrictions_QUERYSTRING"
        }
        excluded_rule {
          name = "NoUserAgent_HEADER"
        }
      }
    }
    visibility_config {
      cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
      metric_name                = "friendly-rule-metric-name"
      sampled_requests_enabled   = true
    }
  }
}
```

my `output.tf` looks like this:

```
output "aws_wafv2_web_acl_af_acl_buddyman_id" {
  value = aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman.id
}
```

When I run `terraform import aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman baf6e249-ec50-45df-ae9f-073e73f83900/waf_acl_buddyman/REGIONAL` it shows:

```
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman: Importing from ID "baf6e249-ec50-45df-ae9f-073e73f83900/waf_acl_buddyman/REGIONAL"...
aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_wafv2_web_acl for import
aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman: Refreshing state... [id=baf6e249-ec50-45df-ae9f-073e73f83900]
╷
│ Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
│
│ While attempting to import an existing object to "aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman", the provider detected that no object exists with the given id. Only
│ pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's configured region or endpoint, or use
│ "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this resource.
╵

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include only the id part and not rest of the stuff in `terraform import`

Comment: I mean `terraform import aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_buddyman baf6e249-ec50-45df-ae9f-073e73f83900`

Comment: no, you need ID/NAME/SCOPE

Answer (score -2):

Output is what Terraform module produces. But you want to take Output as input. Guess why it's empty?
[How to perform import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import).

Comment: Please make sure you answer goes into a bit more detail.